# Qt5 - MinGW64 - qResourceFeatureZlib() entry point not found

Tags: cmake, qt5, mingw-w64, msys2

my software program (GUI) builds/runs fine on Debian GNU/Linux, but I fail to
run it on Win10/MinGW64. I can build it fine, but when I run it, the error message (in
a Win10 system dialog box) is that the (mangled name that I c++filt'ered)
qResourceFeatureZlib() entry point is not found in my executable program.

I researched a bit and discovered that that function is in the Qt5Core library.
Since I was linking againsts Qt5Widgets, I thought it was un-necessary to also link
explicitely against Qt5Core. I linked against Qt5Core, but that did not change the error.

Does this ring a bell to anyboby ?

Many thanks in advance,

Filippo

I am running a development stack on Win10: MSYS2 (64 bits) / MinGW64 using CMake as build system.

Comment: Instead of describing your code, please show it. Please add a minimal *example* to your question post. Without seeing your code, we can only make guesses about what the problem might be..

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are missing the `WIN32` switch at your `add_executable()`.

On Windows, graphical applications (but not console applications) replace the entry point (the first function that gets called) of your application (usually your  `main()`  function) with a different function (`WinMain()`) that contains setup code and will itself call your `main()`.

Read about the `WIN32` switch in the [cmake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html).

Edit: In case you are wondering why the entry point that was not found is called `qResourceFeatureZlib()` instead of `WinMain()`: The [Qt resource system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) enables you (describing this in a very simplified manner) to append a zip file containing any files you want to your executable and to use them as if they were somewhere in a folder with your executable. In order to do so transparently, Qt hooks the entry point of your program, extracts the zip file, and then calls `main()` or `WinMain()`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, setting all the CMake configurations according to the CMake documentation you pointed me to did not fix the issue. That must be something that changed between either gcc versions or Qt versions because I tried to build the software as it was in may 2019 and get this error, while at the time I could build it flawlessly. Still investigating...